# Javascript Image Source Changer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple page that lets me input a name and a photo pops up figured javascript would accomplish that but i'm a javascript newbie and need some help :( here is my code:

```
<img id="myImg" 
src="https:placeholderlink"
width='500' 
alt='Not Loaded' onmouseOver="this.width=550" onmouseOut="this.width=500" />
CBName: <input type="text" id="CBName" name="CBNameBox">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
function CBNameChanger() {
var Source = document.getElementById("CBName").value;
var itemName;
{
    document.write(itemName);
}
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "https:placeholderlink" + itemName ;
}
}
</script>
```

as you see i need to code the take my input and add it to the end of the img url
i was trying to make my image enlarge when you hover the mouse over also that works when an img is present but i cant get an image to load and dont know what im doing wrong lol this is hack an slash code i pieced together from google searches

any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, only you had to do is to join both functions and remove the weird `document.write` between braces.

```js
function CBNameChanger() {
  var Source = document.getElementById("CBName").value;
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://lorempixel.com/" + Source;
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/" width='500' alt="Not Loaded" onmouseOver="this.width=550" onmouseOut="this.width=500" />
<br> CBName: <input type="text" id="CBName" name="CBNameBox" value="50/50/">
<button onclick="CBNameChanger()">Submit</button>
```